# How to add onKeyDown event for a flatpickr element?

Tags: javascript, vue-component, flatpickr

I would like to add onKeyDown event for a flatpickr element in my page.
Currently I have the below code, but this is not working. The event is not getting fired. Any help is appreciated.

```
const dob = flatpickr('#date_of_birth', {
    allowInput: true,
    altInput: true,
    altFormat: "m-d-Y",
    dateFormat: "m-d-Y",
    wrap: true,
});

window.onload = function() {
    if(dob) {
        dob.config.onKeyDown.push(function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
            console.log("Date Value: " + dateStr); // not printed
        });
    }
}
```

Edit: I am using [Flatpickr](https://github.com/ankurk91/vue-flatpickr-component) as a Vue component in my application.

Comment: The [documentation](https://flatpickr.js.org/events/) doesn't list `onKeyDown` as an event hook. You may want to try setting a `keydown` event handler on the HTML element that represents the flatpickr and in that handler, trigger a supported hook.

Comment: Yes, but I would like to modify the date field on my page, when I start typing numbers. Say I try to enter date as: 05032021 (in format: mmddyyyy), and as soon as I enter 05, I want to append a hyphen to the result, so it should be like: 05-03-2021 finally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I was able to get the onKeyDown event working with the below code:

```
const dob = flatpickr('#date_of_birth', {
    allowInput: true,
    altInput: true,
    altFormat: "m-d-Y",
    dateFormat: "m-d-Y",
    wrap: true,
    onKeyDown: (selectedDates, dateStr, instance, event) => {
        if(event.keyCode != 8) {
            var ele = document.activeElement;
            var val = ele.value;
              
            if (val.length == 2 || val.length == 5) {
                val += '-';
            }

            ele.value = val;
            ele.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
          }
    },
});
```

Hope it helps someone out there in future.